# I18n of XSD validation error messages in Java

Tags: java, xml, localization, xsd, jaxp

I perform XSD XML validation using the following classes:

```
import javax.xml.validation.Schema;
import javax.xml.validation.SchemaFactory;
import javax.xml.validation.Validator;
```

The problem is that XSD error messages returned by validator are always in English language. Is it possible to call locale-aware validation with JAXP API?

Comment: That's Localization, actually. You need localized messages as oppose to externalize them. BTW. If there is no property like localizedMessage (which is common for exceptions), you could simply externalize English messages (that would be i18n).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Apparently there's no way to achieve what I want.

Answer (score 1):

JAXP is an API; it is up to the actual implementation (for example, `Apache Xerces`) to provide localization-aware messages.

Normally, though, system-level libraries and implementations (such as JAXP & Xerces) will provide messages localized based on the system's default locale (whatever is returned from the expression `java.util.Locale.getDefault()`); this is, again, OS-specific.

On Microsoft Windows, for example, you can change your system's default locale using the `Regional Settings` window.

If you want, you can override the "default locale" used by the JVM by specifying the `user.language` and `user.region` system properties (for example, `-Duser.language=fr` and `-Duser.region=CA` would make the JVM yield "Canadian French" as a default locale. Eventually, this setting will get to JAXP's code. If Xerces provides Canadian French resource bundles, then Canadian French messages will be emitted.

Comment: The problem is that I want to pass the locale at the runtime.

Comment: The JAXP standard doesn't provide means for specifying locale at runtime. I believe that the reason behind it is that it's highly unusual to really _need_ those messages being available in multiple locales at runtime. It's not the type of messages that typically appear to end-users, but to administrators; that's why, I believe, it was enough for the JAXP spec to suffice with one locale - the system's locale. Of course, it is possible that certain JAXP implementations provide a way to specify locales at runtime... but then you'll be binding yourself to a particular JAXP implementation.

Answer (score 1):

It should print error messages in Japanese, only if it exist the resource file inside
java.xml\com\sun\org\apache\xerces\internal\impl\msg\XMLSchemaMessages_ja.properties
But I didnt find how to add more languages.

```
Validator validator = schema.newValidator();
validator.setErrorHandler(errorHandler);
validator.setProperty("http://apache.org/xml/properties/locale", Locale.forLanguageTag("ja"));
```

Hope it helps.